# How to reinstall system Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

Unfortunately I’ve managed to delete my system Ruby on OS X Yosemite and I'm struggling to re-install it.

I've read through the answers detailed here:

- https://superuser.com/a/227653/107432
- https://superuser.com/questions/545406/i-deleted-ruby-framework-how-can-i-get-it-back

However, when I use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to try and bring back Ruby.framework the app just hangs like so:

[image: Pacifist stalling]

Are there any other means to get hold of Ruby 2.0 for OS X Yosemite and re-install it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Richard did you try implementing @madsy 's answer? please let us know how it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

What about reinstalling Yosemite without formatting the hard drive? I'm sure that will fix it without deleting any of your personal files.